# Efficiently managing connections, prepared statements and ResulSet

Tags: java

**Review**: Please review the `User` class, mainly CRUD operations, `getUsers`, `insert`, `delete` method and `Connection` class.

**Background**: A `User` class implementing an interface `IUser` that provides a function `getUsers` that returns either `ArrayList` of `UserBean`s or throws an `Exception` as per the contract, caller handles all kinds of exceptions. Also provided insert and delete.

Connection to `MySQL DataSource` is `static` and implemented as `Singleton` to be shared between `User` and other classes. Didn't want to use `DataSource` provider by the container and depend on it, for the purpose to make it easy for deployment in different environments.

**IUser**

```
public interface IUser {
    ArrayList<UserBean> getUsers() throws SQLException;
    UserBean insert(String emailAddress) throws SQLException;
    void delete(int id) throws SQLException;
}
```

**User**

```
public class User implements IUser {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public User() {
        dataSource = Connection.getDataSource();
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<UserBean> getUsers() throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        ArrayList<UserBean> userBeans = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT user.id, user.emailAddress FROM user");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while(resultSet.next()) {
                UserBean userBean = new UserBean(resultSet.getInt("user.id"), resultSet.getString("user.emailAddress"));
                userBeans.add(userBean);
            }
        } finally {
            if(preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
            if(resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
        }
        return userBeans;
    }

    @Override
    public UserBean insert(final String emailAddress) throws SQLException {
        UserBean userBean = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();) {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user(emailAddress) VALUES(?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, emailAddress);

            if(preparedStatement.executeUpdate() != 0) {
                try (ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                    if(generatedKeys.next()) {
                        userBean = new UserBean(generatedKeys.getInt(1), emailAddress, null);
                    }
                }
            };
        } finally {
            if(preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
        }
        return userBean;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(final int id) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();) {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            if(preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**UserBean**

```
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String emailAddress;

    public UserBean(int id, String emailAddress) {
        this.id = id;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

}
```

**Connection**

```
public class Connection {

    private static MysqlDataSource dataSource;

    public synchronized static MysqlDataSource getDataSource() {
        if (dataSource != null) return dataSource;

        dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        if(System.getenv("DEVELOPMENT") != null) {
            dataSource.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Sales?authReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
            dataSource.setUser("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("pass1");
        } else {
            dataSource.setURL("jdbc:mysql://foo.bar.rds.example.com:3306/Entitlement?authReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true");
            dataSource.setUser("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("pass2");
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The User class**

Quite straightforward. However, the use of try-with-resources blocks is inconsistent. For some objects try-with-resources is used, for others the "old" construct using external null init and a finally block. Also note, that you can create multiple closable resources in a single try clause, e.g.

```
@Override
public ArrayList<UserBean> getUsers() throws SQLException {
    // moved out to shorten the line below
    String query = "SELECT user.id, user.emailAddress FROM user";
    ArrayList<UserBean> userBeans = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    ) {
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            UserBean userBean = new UserBean(resultSet.getInt("user.id"), resultSet.getString("user.emailAddress"));
            userBeans.add(userBean);
        }
    }
    return userBeans;
}
```

I recommend refactoring to 100% try-with-resources and no finally blocks.

Good point: you close *all* closable resources including result sets and statements. You wouldn't believe how many people forget that.

**General setup**

Is there more than one implementation of IUser? If not, why do you need an interface? I'd simply delete IUser and recreate it via refactoring if I need a second implementation, not before.

Static datasource with the singleton antipattern: BAD idea. See http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/ https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/11/clean-code-talks-global-state-and.html http://www.drdobbs.com/once-is-not-enough/184401625 just to share a few links. Better: inject this into the User class. If you don't want to go through the hassle of putting it all into a CDI container, pass it in as a constructor parameter.

The Connection class itself: first of all, the name "Connection" collides with the JDBC Connection, I'd try to find another name. I guess the hardcoded database parameters are just for a quick and dirty setup. If not, these should come from an external source like a configuration file. After such a change, there's especially no more need to switch between different environments via code.

Comment: Thanks mtj, very constructive, while I'm going through it, can you please add some information on configuration files for dev and production, agree very much, I'm not familiar on how to do that in Java

Comment: for configuration files, i found this http://www.opencodez.com/java/read-config-file-in-java.htm

Comment: Yes, Properties are the way to go, have a look into the API. If you want to be flexible for dev/test/prod-environments and the application is standalone, just pass in the path to the properties file as a program argument and read it via Properties.load().

Comment: `just pass in the path to the properties file as a program argument` I usually use the IDE, set the environment variable and then run the server

Comment: `If you don't want to go through the hassle of putting it all into a CDI container` an example for for CDI container please?

Comment: Starter tutorial: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/cdi/building-a-cdi-2-standalone-java-application  - but really, you should be comforable with the ins-and-outs of Java before tackling this.

Comment: Regarding the IDE comment I overlooked before: in eclipse, you can open the run confiuration for your project and add arguments. All other IDEs are bound to have something similar.

Comment: Oh I understand now what you mean by CDI, sometimes the problem is with accessing the settings of the container, if I host on AWS, it's cumbersome that's why I wanted to make the application self sufficient and not depend on the container. That's why the DataSource is hard coded but certainly I'll pass data source it as a dependency in the constructor from the caller.

Comment: I've implemented the changes across my files, however a hiccup when I try to set placeholder values within `try()`, any suggestions?

Comment: If the prepared statement takes parameters, this cannot be done in a singly try. You'll have to split into an outer try-with-resources for connection and prepared statement, then init the statement and proceed with an inner try-with-resources for the result set. To end this here, please put these technical questions over to Stackoverflow.

Comment: sure, would you mind answering there, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527991/try-with-parameterized-preparedstatements and I think I got the picture as well :)